# Какая разница между вызовом функции и возвратом значения функции?

Tags: javascript

Много перелистал информации, и разница между этими двумя понятиями для меня остается загадкой. Есть понятие вызов функции, например, `show()` - после чего команды в теле функции будут выполнятся, а есть понятие функция возвращает значение с помощью ключевого слова `return`. Если после этого указывается значение, которое функция должна возвратить и выполнение функции завершается. Если после `return` ничего не указать, то вернет `undefined`. Какая разница между вызовом функции и возвратом функции?

---

Пока умозаключения такие:

1. Вызов функции выполняет код функции. Вызовов может быть много, значит результат выполнение кода функции будет однинаковый;
2. return отбирает результат выполнения кода функции у функции и передает его (присваивает его) в код, который вызвал эту функцию. При этом дальнейшее выполнение кода функции прекращается при последующих ее вызовах.

Если что не так поправьте.

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109287/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80

Comment: Функция может возвращать значения, может не возвращать. Если функция значение не возвращает, оно нигде в коде далее не используется, а, например, выполняются некоторые действия в окне браузера.  Если вызов функция возвращает значение, то оно является вспомогательный звеном при вычислении. Возвращается при помощи return.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function show(arg) {
  const p = 5;
  const k = 9;
}

function showValue(arg) {
  const result = arg * 2
  return result;
}

function editValueB(arg) {
  b = arg;
}

const a = show(1); // в a запишется undefined, потому что return'a нету
let b = showValue(4); // в b запишется то, что стоит в функции после return
console.log('a = show(1) -->', a);
console.log('b = showValue(4) -->', b);
editValueB(23); // функция editValueB изменит значение переменной b
console.log('editValueB(23) -->', b);
```